# Blank page shown on redirect laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

so created a new method in my controller called new_consultation and tried to redirect to it but it shows a blank page. When i try to use the default methods like create, show, edit and delete they work properly and display as expected.

My Controller

```
public function new_consultation() {
        // i used echo to try and see if this method was being called
        echo "l";
    }
```

My redirect

```
return redirect('/consultation/new_consultation');
```

And in my route

```
Route::any('/consultation/new_consultation', 'ConsultationController@new_consultation')->name('consultation.new_consultation');
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Try Route::get instead of Route::any

Comment: Did you create any view for `new_consultation` ?

Comment: Not necessery if it is just echoing

Comment: I think some thing is wrong, please make `APP_DEBUG=true` in `.env` file and then clear configuration caches and error will be displayed while loading the route.

Comment: @SagarGautam i set APP_DEBUG to true and cleared cache but still the same problem. Just realised that it keeps redirecting to the show() method in my resourceful controller when i put an echo statement in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your error reporting is disabled. 
make sure in  your .env file

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

if it's still not show anything, put this following code in your controller method or constructor to check if you have any error.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

this is to enable error reporting in php.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. My error reporting was disabled but i found out the solution after enabling the laravel errors.

Comment: @DouglasHosea anytime mate. I have edited the answer for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

This might be an old thread but my mistake when I encountered this problem was I didn't return the redirect i just called redirect:

**correct**

```
return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('Item updated');
```

**incorrect**

```
redirect()->back()->withSuccess('Item updated');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you named your route, you can try redirecting with the route name like so

```
return redirect()->route('consultation.new_consultation');
```

Read more about redirects here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects

Comment: Still the same issue occuring